# Does there exist a convergent series $\sum _{n=1}^\infty a_n$ of positive terms such that $na_n $ does not converge to $0$ ?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does there exist a convergent series $\sum _{n=1}^\infty a_n$ of positive terms such that $na_n $ does not converge to $0$ ? I only know that if such a series exists then the sequence $\{a_n\}$ cannot be decreasing . Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: hint : $\displaystyle\sum_{n  \text{ is a square}} \frac{1}{n} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider
$$
a_n=\left\{\begin{array}{}
\frac1n&\text{if $n=2^k$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$}\\
\frac1{n^2}&\text{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.
$$

Comment: Very good answer. The sequence has to be positive though, this can be done with a minor edit.

Comment: @i707107: fixed

Comment: @i707107: Many times questions that are about non-negative numbers are asked about positive numbers. Often, the proof is more complicated, but no more instructive, if we are required to use positive numbers rather than non-negative numbers. In my edited answer, the $\frac1{n^2}$ draws attention away from the important part of the answer, but adds nothing of value other than to make all the terms positive.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there exist such series. One cute example is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ where:
$$
a_n = \begin{cases}
0, & \text{if the decimal expansion of $n$ contains a $9$} \\
\frac{1}{n}, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

See for example [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1343038/does-the-harmonic-series-converge-if-you-throw-out-the-terms-containing-a-9/1343048#1343048) for more details.

(If you insist on *positive* terms, replace $0$ with something tending to $0$ quickly.)