# If $\big\{n(k);k\in \mathbb{N}\big\}$ be set of all natural numbers none of whose digits is $6$, does $\frac1{n(1)}+\frac1{n(2)}+\ldots$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, summation, divergent-series

> If $\big\{n(k);k\in \mathbb{N}\big\}$ be set of all natural numbers none of whose digits is $6$, does $$\frac1{n(1)}+\frac1{n(2)}+\ldots+\frac1{n(k)}+\ldots$$ converge?

Actually,  I have tried of using comparison test to show that it does *converge* or *diverge*, but I don't even know it converges or not, and as it is a *sub*-*series* of  $$1+\frac 12+ \frac 13+\frac14+....$$  which diverges very slowly, hence calculators are not helpful to determine it's nature.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: See [Does the harmonic series converge if you throw out the terms containing a 9
?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1343038/does-the-harmonic-series-converge-if-you-throw-out-the-terms-containing-a-9) (same type of argument applies with $6$ instead of $9$)

Comment: I think you can show that $\{n(k) : k \in \mathbb{N}\}$ does not contain arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions, so $\sum_k \frac{1}{n(k)} < \infty$ follows if you believe Erdös's conjecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only $9^k$ such numbers with $k$ digits; they together contribute at most $9^k\cdot \frac1{10^{k-1}}$.